# Как сделать вкладки с помощью php

Tags: php, html

Нужно сделать вкладки на php примерно как здесь на сайте

"Вопросы Метки Участники Знаки Исследования"

После нажатия происходит загрузка этой же страницы но с доп. параметрами в $_GET, и исходя из этого php выводит нужный шаблон

Проблема в том как сменить стиль вкладки?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/?sort=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5

Вот так нужно

Только через php? И здесь так же через php сделано? Имеется ввиду добавление class=active...

---

Я ведь говорил что содержимое грузится только по клику. И только в один див)) Мне не нужен jquery, мне нужны обычные вкладки с перезагрузкой страницы.
Вкладки на jquery это 99% всех туториалов в инете, сделать их просто. Но для меня они не подходят. Сделал по своему. Меня только интересовало как это реализовано на этом сайте?

Comment: я понял из вашего вопроса...ничего!

Comment: в смысле сделать активной ? ну в php определяйте на какую вкладку  ткнули и присваивайте ей класс "active", создавайте для этого правило css

Comment: Делай на css и javascript

Comment: Напиши нормально вопрос

Comment: $_GET - это глобальный массив, в котором содержится переменные с GET запроса...

Answer (score 1):

Я очень долго пытался вас понять и, возможно, мне это так и не удалось. НО.

```
<div id="menu">
<div <?if(isset($_GET['questions']))echo 'class="active"'?>>Вопросы</div>
<div <?if(isset($_GET['marks']))echo 'class="active"'?>>Метки</div>
<div <?if(isset($_GET['members']))echo 'class="active"'?>>Участники</div>
<div <?if(isset($_GET['signs']))echo 'class="active"'?>>Знаки</div>
<div <?if(isset($_GET['expeditions']))echo 'class="active"'?>>Исследования</div>
</div>
```